# Laravel wrong method

Tags: laravel

Laravel basics:

I have the following routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pps',  'as' => 'pps.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function (){

Route::get('/index', 'PPS\PPSController@index')->name('index');
/**
 * Templates
 */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'templates',  'as' => 'templates.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function (){

    Route::get('/', 'PPS\Template\TemplateController@index')->name('index');
    /**
     * Sequence group
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'sequenceGroup',  'as' => 'sequenceGroup.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function (){

        Route::get('/', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('/create', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@create')->name('create');
        Route::post('/store', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@store')->name('store');
        Route::get('/edit/{sequenceGroup}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::put('/update/{sequenceGroup}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@update')->name('update');
        Route::delete('/delete/{sequenceGroup}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceGroupController@delete')->name('delete');
    });
    /**
     * Sequence template
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'sequenceTemplates',  'as' => 'sequenceTemplates.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function (){

        Route::get('/{sequenceGroup}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('/create/{sequenceGroup}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@create')->name('create');
        Route::post('/store', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@store')->name('store');
        Route::get('/edit/{sequenceTemplate}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::put('/update/{sequenceTemplate}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@update')->name('update');
        Route::delete('/delete/{sequenceTemplate}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@delete')->name('delete');
    });
});


});
```

When i update the sequence group, everything works well.
But when i will update the sequence template, laravel goes allways to edit method and not to the update method.

Here my form:

```
 <form action="{{ route('pps.templates.sequenceTemplates.update', $sequenceTemplate->id) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('put') }}
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">@lang('pps.name')</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name', $sequenceTemplate->name) }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="description" class="control-label">@lang('pps.description')</label>
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" value="{{ old('description', $sequenceTemplate->description) }}">
                @if ($errors->has('description'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@lang('pps.save')</button>
        </form>
```

The controller:

```
    public function edit(SequenceTemplate $sequenceTemplate)
{

    return view('pps.template.sequenceTemplate.edit', compact('sequenceTemplate'));
}

public function update(UpdateSequenceTemplateRequest $request, SequenceTemplate $sequenceTemplate)
{

    $sequenceTemplate->update($request->except('_token', '_method'));
    return redirect()->route('pps.templates.sequenceTemplate.index')->withSuccess(__('sequenceTemplateUpdated'));
}
```

The request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\PPS\Template;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateSequenceTemplateRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'sequence_group_id' => 'required|integer',
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3',

    ];
}
}
```

What is wrong? i do not find the bug.

Comment: atleast show us the full error you are getting

Comment: too long, Not well formatted

Comment: Sorry for long code. I do not have any error message. in my form, i go to the route: pps.templates.sequenceTemplates.update
After all i know, laravel should go to :             Route::put('/update/{sequenceTemplate}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@update')->name('update');
instead, the program goes to             Route::get('/edit/{sequenceTemplate}', 'PPS\Template\SequenceTemplateController@edit')->name('edit');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fill the form and press submit button, Laravel validates the data and redirects you back because there is no `sequence_group_id` in the form and the field is required:

```
'sequence_group_id' => 'required|integer',
```

And you don't see any error message because you're not trying to display it for `sequence_group_id`. To test it put this to the top of the form:

```
Errors: {{ dump($errors->all()) }}
```

And try to submit the form.